# git diff --ignore-matching-lines ignores all lines

Tags: git, diff

I'm trying to use git's `--ignore-matching-lines`, but running into some weird behavior. Here's the output of a plain `git diff`:

```bash
$ git diff test.txt
```

```
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 602c47d1cb..82655814c5 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
-Hello world
+Hello whitespace world
+
 
 Lots of blank lines
 
 Goodbye world
+
```

However, if I run

```
$ git diff --ignore-matching-lines='^$' test.txt
```

I get no output

Why is this ignoring the change that adds the word `whitespace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by how '`$`' itself is interpreted, as detailed in "[How does `git diff --ignore-matching-lines` work](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2021/08/13/how-does-git-diff-ignore-matching-lines-work/)", by [Sjoerd Langkemper](https://github.com/Sjord) (also a [Stack Overflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182971/sjoerd)):

> Git runs each regex over each line.
> These lines end in a newline, so our regex is actually checked against:
>
> ```
> His bill will hold more than his belican,\n
> ```
>
> Where `\n` stands for a newline character.
>
> When we have a change that adds an empty line, the regex is ran against a single byte string consisting of `\n`.
> How do we match that?
>
> It’s easier to use something like `--ignore-blank-lines` to ignore blank lines.

(Check, by the way, if [`git diff --ignore-blank-line`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---ignore-blank-lines) is a good option in your particular case)

> However, this does not work well together with other regular expressions that we want to ignore.
> If we want to ignore a change that performs both an uninteresting belly-related change and adds an uninteresting empty line, our regular expressions we give to `-I` need to match both for the change to be hidden.
> So we need a regular expression that matches an empty line, and `--ignore-blank-lines` and other white space related options don’t change that.
>
> An empty line cannot be matched with `^$`.
>
> - `^` matches both the beginning of the line and the beginning of the buffer.
> - Similarly, `$` matches both the end of the line as the end of the buffer.
>
> All changed lines end in a newline, just before the end of the buffer.
> This means that `^$` **matches every changed line**.
> The newline at the end starts a new line, and is immediately followed by the end of the buffer.
>
> ```
> … his belican,\n
>                ↑
>                ^ matches because \n starts a new line
>                $ matches because the buffer ends here
> ```

That would explain why a `--ignore-matching-lines='^$'` is  ignoring the change that adds the word `whitespace`: it is ignoring *all* the lines!

> To match more precisely, we can use `` \` `` to match the start of the buffer, and `\'` to match the end of the buffer.
> An empty line can thus be matched with:
>
> ```
>  \`\n\'
> ```
>
> Where `\n` is an actual newline, not `backslash-n`.
> This needs much escaping to enter correctly in a shell:
>
> ```
> git diff -I $'\\`\n\\\'' …
> ```